# incorrect height in Chrome when "-webkit-appearance: none" and value="" on <input> tag

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

In Chrome v17.0.963.79 on Windows 7, I seem to be having an inexplicable problem when applying  the `-webkit-appearance: none` style to an `<input>` tag. The problem is as follows:

I have a stylesheet, let's call it *potatofoot.css*, which consists of the code

```css
.tbl {
    display: table;
}

.tblRow {
    display: table-row;
}

.tblCell {
    display: table-cell;
}

input {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}​
```

and I have an html file, let's call it *blech.html*, which contains the code

```
<div class="tbl">

  <div class="tblRow">
    <label class="tblCell">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="tblCell" value="I'M NOT EMPTY! OH, YEAH!">
  </div><!--end tblRow-->

</div><!--end tbl-->
```

This displays fine (see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steinera/Ymrm9/1/)). But when I empty the `value` attribute, as in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/steinera/VwA4t/), the entire table grows from a height of 26px to a height of 31px, the label moves to the bottom, and the input stays at the top.

However, if I remove `-webkit-appearance: none;`, everything shows up the same [with](http://jsfiddle.net/steinera/mAqyt/) and [without](http://jsfiddle.net/steinera/cdT4u/) out the value attribute being filled.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested it with Chrome developer tools - experiencing the same.

What's happening is that using `-webkit-appearance: none` seems to set the `display: table-cell` internally.

If you override this by setting `display: inline-block` (as it is *without* `-webkit-appearance: none`) it is displayed correctly.

Comment: Huh. Does that mean this is a bug?

Comment: Not sure. But nevertheless I think you should wrap the input into a DIV with display: table-cell. It seems that webkit doesn't like display: table-cell on the input element (you used class="tblCell").

Comment: I wouldn't be surprized if it's a bug. Chrome is generally buggy when you start to use uncommon features.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <input type="text" value="">
```

remove the class attribute and it works fine andtry to write css code for input field in its container because it is already defined in stylesheet plus was being conflicted with using another class tblCell